# What's the type of a arrow function (or a normal function) in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, types

So, I'm trying to type the props of a component

```js
interface CardProps {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  image?: string;
  handle: Function;
}

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({ title, content, handle, image }: any) => {
  return (
    <CardContainer onPress={handle}>
{/*...*/}
  )
```

But when I run it, it gives me a error:
`Don't use 'Function' as a type. The 'Function' type accepts any function-like value. It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs. It also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with 'new'. If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape.`

The handle is like this

```js
 <Card
    {/**/}
        handle={() =>
          navigation.navigate("Verbete", {
            title: verbetes.nazismo.title,
            content: verbetes.nazismo.content,
          })
      />
```

I want to know what is the type of a function

Comment: You say "it" gives you an error, but that's not a TypeScript error.  Presumably that's a linter?  If so maybe you want to tag the question with the appropriate linter?

Comment: The type to use depends on what data you're passing into `handle`, and if anything needs to be returned. If nothing is passed in and nothing is returned, then the type will be: `handle: () => void`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function takes no argument and doesn't return anything, then its type is `() => void`. Otherwise you have to list the arguments, the types of the arguments, and the return type.

Also, you're not typing correctly the component itself. It should look like this instead:

```
const Card = ({ title, content, handle, image }: CardProps) => {
  ... 
}
```